# vcr breaks from multiple web requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vcr

A project that I am working on has integration tests which actually go out and hit a 3rd party api over the wire...  Running these tests takes a *very* long time.  I suggested that we implement something like VCR so that the data the tests interact with can be captured as fixtures, and improve reliability and speed of these tests.

I don't have access to the codebase at this moment, but I believe the tests were doing something like this:

```
before do
  login_some_user
end

after do
  make_web_request_to_clear_items_in_cart
end

it "adds some items to the user's cart" do
  make_web_request_to_add_item_to_a_cart
end
```

So basically the before block was making a web request, the example was making a totally different request, and an after block (which I know is not ideal to use) made a 3rd request to clean up records that had been created by the example.

I setup an around block in spec_helper that captures web requests and stores them named after the example.  However, after running the tests repeatedly I found that they became extremely flakey, sometimes passing, sometimes not..  I tried wrapping the before and after blocks in a separate VCR.use_cassette block call, but it made no difference.

I am wondering if I am missing something, and if there's a way to handle multiple requests like this or what?

Comment: remember to keep deleting your cassette if you keep adding requests

Answer (score 9):

VCR can handle multiple requests. From you pseudo-code, you would have the following:

```
it "adds some items to the user's cart" do
 VCR.use_cassette "your_path/cassette_name" do
   login_some_user
   make_web_request_to_add_item_to_a_cart
   make_web_request_to_clear_items_in_cart
 end
end
```

The cassette `your_path/cassette_name` would contain all 3 web requests.

Your issue likely comes from using `before` and `after` blocks. See [Myron Marston explanation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vcr-ruby/db3jH_FKark/Dg6EeLO8uSMJ) of how VCR handles the `before(:all)` hook.